# Share internet and network between two linksys ADSL Modem LAN to LAN

Tags: networking, routing

I have two Linksys modems that one of them are connected to internet ADSL (PPPoE) and want to connect another one to first one by LAN (LAN to LAN) in order gain internet access in far place.
What I did  is depend on the following guidance:
linksys.com/ca/support-article?articleNum=132275

1. Main Modem
   ip: 192.168.1.1
   DHCP: enable
   Encapsulation: RFC xxxx PPPoE
   Internet username and password Done and main modem works fine.
2. Second Modem
   ip:192.168.1.111 (because DHCP range of main modem was 192.168.1.100)
   DHCP: Disable
   Encapsulation: ??? (What should I select?)
   options: (1)Bridged Mode Only (2) RFC Bridged (3) RFC Routed (4)IPoA (5)RFC PPPoE (6)RFC PPPoA

For options PPPoE and PPPoA it needs ADSL username/password. In both Bridged modes does not works! In Routed mode it needs Internet IP Address, Gateway, DNSs etc
[image of settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iuq9.png)
Which encapsulation should I select for second modem?
Both modems are connected together via their LAN ports and there isn't WAN port on them.
Note that in Routed mode, values for IP Settings is a must and it didn't allowed me save the settings without IP Settings in Routed mode. In another encapsulations mode, there isn't IP Settings.
[image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLWuF.png)

Comment: Telling us it doesn't work isn't helpful. What specifically did it do or not do?

Comment: Try bridged mode only

Comment: I mentioned what I did! Set encapsulation on second modem as Bridged mode and DHCP:Disabled and connect two modems via LAN port. Even second modem does not detected via network!